# AS3 simple save function in flash for desktop application xml

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, restore, savechanges

I'm making a basic drag and drop application in flash. I would like all that is in the current flash screen to be saved into an XML file. (or any other straight forward solution) How should I go about this?

I want a simple save function on a mouse click so that when you click 'Save', all of the current arrangement is saved somewhere and ready to be reloaded when the player clicks 'restore'.

Thanks all. (P.S i'm a designer and novice to AS3, I studied AS2)

```
stop();

Mouse.hide();
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,follow);
function follow(evt:MouseEvent){
    tweezer_cur.x = mouseX;
    tweezer_cur.y = mouseY;
}

//Resetter btn ---------------------

reset_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startover);

function startover(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
 gotoAndPlay(1);
 }

//------------------------------ fullscreen
function setFullScreen():void {
if (stage.displayState== "normal") {
stage.displayState="fullScreen";
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
} else {
stage.displayState="normal";
}
}

fullbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goFull); 
    // btn declared - - - - - - - - 

    function goFull(event:MouseEvent):void {
 setFullScreen();
 };

 //---------------------------- print project



printme_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startPrintJobHandler, false, 0, true);

    function startPrintJobHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
     var printJob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();
     printJob.start()

     var printJobOptions:PrintJobOptions = new PrintJobOptions(); 
     printJobOptions.printAsBitmap = true; 

     printJob.addPage(artworkContainer, null, printJobOptions);

     printJob.send();
 }

 //--- all the draggables will live here
dragme.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
dragme.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);

function pickupObject(event:MouseEvent):void {
event.target.startDrag(true);
}
 function dropObject(event:MouseEvent):void {
 event.target.stopDrag();
}
```

Comment: Do you speak English?

Comment: You can certainly do this using a `SharedObject`. Please tell us the specific steps you have already taken and where you are running into issues.

Comment: Hello, It's quite loose at the minute to be honest. I haven't taken any action, I don't have a clue where to begin - sorry :-( Any pointers?

Comment: You say you're making a drag and drop application, but you're asking about a save functionality. You should be able to post at least the code you've done for the drag and drop functionality thus far. It will give us more information about the type of data you're attempting to save/restore.

Comment: Does it have to be saved to XML?  There's a really great thing called a `Shared Object`...

Comment: Hello, I have bundled in the code. No it doesn't have too be XML. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can this be an AIR application?  If so you can save files (like XML) directly to the computer using [FileStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html)

Comment: It doesn't have to be, although I am considering extending it's publication/deployment in Zinc. Cheers